# How can I properly loop through and correctly display each of these marker names?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm working on a google maps application in which the user clicks on a marker and submit imformation through an info window. Currently I'm trying to display the name of each marker at the top of the info window. The markers are loaded from a database and xml file.

I'm able to display a name on the info window but it is only for the **first** marker in the database. that name appears for every marker when i want each name to be displayed appropriately for each marker. any help would be appreciated. thank you

here's the form that is displayed when the user clicks on a marker

```
<div id="form">
  <table>
  <tr><td>Name:</td> <td> </td> </tr>
           <label id="name" style="color: #0026ff"></label>
        <tr><td>questindicator:</td> <td><select id="questType" onchange="questLogic()">  
        <option value="null">Select quest</option>
        <option value="quest1">Name of Quest</option>
        <option value="quest2">Name of Quest<</option>      
        </select> </td> </tr>
             <tr><td><input type='button' value='Save' onclick='saveData()'/></td></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

And here is where I'm loading the markers in

```
      downloadUrl('call.php', function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName('marker');
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(markers, function(markerElem) {
          var name = markerElem.getAttribute('name');              //name of marker

           document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = name;  //displaying marker name in info window

          var content = document.getElementById('form');


           marker.addListener('click', function() {

//setting contents of infowindow
                  infowindow.setContent(content); 
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
          });
        });


      });
```

Comment: Where is the `marker` variable defined? Also, is it a `MediaQueryList` or something?

Comment: marker is declared globally at the top right after <script>, before my initmap function. i just declared it as var marker;